# Bar Button Item in only one of the tab bar controller navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a tab bar controller with 4 views controller, and have this tab bar controller in a navigation controller.

I want to display a UIBarButtonItem for just one specific view controller of the tab bar controller.

I tried to use the following

```
if (tabBarController.selectedViewController == customTourViewController)
    {
        [tabBarController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:done];
    }
```

But the button doesn't show up.

If I put every view controller in a navigation controller, then the button shows up for only that view, but I end up having 2 navigation bars.

Is there any way I can implement the first solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In my individual view controllers for the individual tabs, I have the following in the one that needs the button:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}
```

And in the view controllers that don't need the button, I have:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

So, if it's not working for you, I'm not sure if it's your reference to `tabBarController` without the `self` designation (if I omit the `self` I get a compiler error). And where is this code because if it's in your tabBarController subclass, then you want `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`, right? Do you have your own ivar defined for that variable name? Or are you sure that `done` is defined properly (i.e. not `nil`)? Or are you sure this code is being called at all (perhaps set a breakpoint or insert a `NSLog` and make sure this code is being reached)?

Comment: Saved the day mate! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can implement viewWillDisappear in the same view where you need the button.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];        
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer above is exactly what I needed, just wanted to convert it to Swift for those in the future.

I've added the code below to the view controller that required the bar button (I've created an add button for this example):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: nil)
}
```

In the view controllers that don't require this bar button, simply add the code below

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
}
```

You use `viewWillAppear` vice `viewDidAppear` because you want the bar button to appear every time the user goes to the designated view controller.

Simply put, `viewDidAppear` is called once at runtime, `viewWillAppear` will be called every time the view controller is visited.